# What can remove the bane effects of Elder Runes in Dungeon of the Mad Mage?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, gm-techniques, published-adventures, waterdeep-dungeon-of-the-mad-mage

In the campaign *Dungeon of the Mad Mage* there are bane effects on Elder Runes that are cast like symbol.  One of the runes mentions specifically that it can be dispelled by *remove curse* or *greater restoration* and the others with lingering affects say nothing.  Am I to infer (as the GM) that these other effects cannot be dispelled and just have to wear off over time?

Answer (score 2):

### Don’t infer - look at the rules

One of the runes can be dispelled by *[remove curse](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Remove%20Curse#content)* or *[greater restoration](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Spells:Greater%20Restoration#content)*, so it can be.

The others don’t say how they can be removed so you need to look at the rules on things that *could* remove them.

If the effect is a curse, then  *remove curse*  removes them because that is what it does.

If the effect is one of the things that *greater restoration* fixes, then that fixes it.

If the effect is one of the things that *[lesser restoration](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Spells:Lesser%20Restoration#content)* fixes, then that fixes it.

If the effect is a spell (so not *like* [*Symbol*](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Symbol#h-Symbol) but actually *symbol*) then [*dispel magic*](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Dispel%20Magic#h-Dispel%20Magic) will work.

And so on ...

Answer (score 0):

**Yes infer - you don't seem too far off.**

I see you have already noted the one rune that explicitly mentions what can help.  As you probably are aware your goto options are *Restorations*, *remove curse*, or *Dispel Magic*.

*Restoration* - It is blatantly obvious restorations can only help with the one rune where it was explicitly stated the rest don't meet the conditons.

*Remove Curse* - No other symbol mentions a curse so this goes out the window for all but the explicitly stated one.

*Dispel Magic* - I only see one case that mentions a spell effect.

A quick rundown of the runes with lingering effects and how to get rid of it:

## Anrath

*Greater Restoration* and *Remove Curse* (Explicitly stated)

## Korombos

*Dispel Magic* and Time (1 Min)

## Angras

Time (24 Hrs)

## Ullathar

Time (24 Hrs)

## Lammath

Time (24 Hrs)

## Nchasme

Time (1 Hr)

Now some may want to argue about things being "like" *Symbol* - but the explicit text does not say that Halaster casts it as Symbol just that players can if they know the spell and rune.

> With years of study, any creature that can cast the symbol spell can learn an elder rune and add it to the selection of symbols that can be created with the spell.

But lets say for arguments sake that it is *Symbol* and that some of these effects are magical and can be dispelled.  That is a level 7 spell and if you are trying to dispel magic the DC is 17.  Personally I would allow dispel magic for all the options that have only time because I feel like a 24 hrs wait with no fix for some of these runes is a bit much.